# float property not working in HtmlWorker(iText)

Tags: java, css, itext

I am trying to apply float property to a div in itext. The content is an HTML content

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 72, 108, 180);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, servletOutputStream);
document.open();

HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
StyleSheet style = new StyleSheet();
style.loadStyle("class-name", "float", "left");

 htmlWorker.setStyleSheet(style);
 htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(stringBuilder.toString()));
```

The above code doesn't work for float, but for other properties like size,color,etc.
What could be the possible solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTMLWorker has been discontinued in favor of XML Worker.

The project :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/

The demo :

http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/

The documentation :

http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html